# Using SoundCloud Getters

Tags: javascript, soundcloud, getter

I'm having trouble using the SoundCloud getter getCurrentSound(callback). I'm trying to store the song currently in the widget as a var so I can pass that as a param to one of my ruby methods.

I have tried the following and it's not working:

```
   var current song =  SC.Widget("sc-widget").getCurrentSound()
```

Here is info about the getters SoundCloud uses:
http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget

Comment: What language are you using, is there any code snippet you can post so we can see some context?

Comment: One obvious issue with the code you've posted is that `var current song` isn't a valid variable name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if the documentation doesn't make this clear. The `getCurrentSound()` method is asynchronous, so it does not return a value and instead takes a callback. Try this instead:

```
var widget = SC.Widget(...);
widget.getCurrentSound(function(sound) {
    console.log(sound.title);
});
```

Hope that helps. Let me know if it's still unclear.